# PHP passing a class to another class and using a constant from it

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a constant from a class that I'm passing to another class, but I can't work out how to call it. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong:

```
Class A {
    const TEST = 1;

}

Class B {
    protected $c;

    function func($c) {
        $this->c = $c;

        echo $this->c::TEST; // this doesn't work
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

$b->func($a);
```

Comment: `A::TEST`. It's a constant not a class variable.

Comment: Replace `function func($c) {` with `function func(A $c) {` :)

Comment: @Zaheer Not that that changes anything here…

Comment: `Class B extends A {` and `echo TEST;` should work.

Comment: @Meloman Nope, way off base.

Comment: @deceze Well I tried it here.. https://eval.in/848602

Comment: @Zaheer Well, the `A` wasn't what made it work.

Comment: @deceze my learning box is wide open.. I'd like to know about this..

Comment: @Zaheer It worked in `eval.in` because it's running PHP >= 7.

Comment: @deceze Thanks.. Learned some new stuff.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Accessing constants on instances on properties is only a syntactical ambiguity/incompatibility in PHP versions < 7. What you're doing work fine in versions >= 7. This works just fine in all versions:

```
function func($c) {
    echo $c::TEST;
}
```

In PHP < 7, you'll have to resort to:

```
$c = $this->c;
$c::TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `TEST` is a constant, you access it statically, like `A::TEST`

Check the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: What if you *want* to access it from the instance, since the results may vary?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't understand exactly what you mean. Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45818413/4995957

Answer (score 0):

This only works in php 7.

What you can do in PHP 5 is replace your:

```
echo $this->c::TEST;
```

with:

```
echo A::TEST;
```

or:

```
echo $c::TEST;
```

Comment: These do not do the same thing.

Comment: it depends on what he wants to do, so I give both options. Anyway, the whole point of a constant is that it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A {
  const TEST = 1;
  function getText()
  {
   return static::TEST;
  }
}
```

then use this function (notice static keywords for Inheritance)

```
Class B {
    protected $c;

    function func($c) {
        $this->c = $c;

        echo $this->c->getTest();
    }
}
```